# Export Configuration Profiles from iOS

Tags: iphone, certificate, export, profile

I have a profile on my iPhone that is no longer available elsewhere. However, I would like to install this profile on my iPad. Is there any way to export these certificates? I tried grabbing the TrustCore.sqlite3 file form my iPhone and putting it on my iPad, replacing the one that was there previously, but that did not work after rebooting my iPad. I also tried using the iPhone Configuration Utility but it doesn't allow me to export individual certificates. Does anyone have any idea how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, you can't exact configuration profile from a device. I have also tried with jailbroken phone, but could not find quick solution. I think its security provided by Apple. Otherwise, anyone can retrive installed configuration profile and modify it and re-install it.

Answer given by @obuseme is for provisioning profile. You can get them as mentioned by him. Configuration profiles are different than provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
This can be done for companies that need to extract configuration profiles so that they can deploy it to other devices within the network.
In most cases you would deploy using a tool like jamf.

To gather the configuration profile you can use AppleConfigurator2 or iMazing.

Personally I would use iMazing as AppleConfigurator2 is now old and would suggest using something that might be a little easer for the end user to extract the configuration profile.

I hove done a demo screenshot for you so that you can see it working for my Tennent that I will be deploying the profile out to all users in my workplace.

https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-manage-configuration-profiles
[image: Screenshot]